# Need to set line-height property for varying line-height text

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, line

I have some row-based text content in HTML (appearing in `<p>` tag).

The text content in this row could be either one line or two lines, depending on length of text. For example, if one line, it could have up to 30 words. I want `line-height` to be set automatically depending on number of lines of text.

I guess this would be done using JavaScript or jQuery using an `if` statement. Since I'm a novice in both these languages, I don't know how to meet my requirement. Please guide me writing appropriate code for this with full syntax and not just selected lines.

Also it would be a great help to let me know where to add syntax i.e. inside head or bottom in the body, as it makes a difference.

**Update:**

added a grab on following link -
http://justpaste.it/2t4d

let me know if need more details...thanks!

**update:**
fiddle is available at - http://jsfiddle.net/ravk/M4GSR/

as per fiddel, I want line-height to set automatically whether text is of single line or two lines (no more lines than two)...and fit vertically center to the base div.

Comment: What do you want it to do if you end up with 3 lines of text, or can that happen? Are you really just wanting to have a small, variable amount of text in a fixed dimension box?

Comment: Provide a Fiddle link containing your HTML, CSS and JavaScript code.

Comment: as of now the case is, if text goes max in two lines. the bg box has fixed height...so whether in single line or two lines text will be vertically center align to box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this would be done by using **JAVASCRIPT**

add this code:

```
   <body>
      <p id = 'p'> // your text </p>
    </body>
      <script type = 'text/javascript'>
         p = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-mid')
         for(i in p){   
          no_of_words = p[i].innerHTML.length
          alert(no_of_words)
           if(no_of_words <= 30){
             p[i].style.lineHeight = '100px'
           }
          else{
            p[i].style.lineHeight = '50px'
          }
            }
      </script>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3D2r/6/)

Comment: I added the code inside head tag of my html doc and change id from 'p' to 'chng-txt' as it is in my html-code...but neither alert sounded on refreshing page nor there is any change in line-heights.

Comment: did you change the ID  in `p = document.getElementById('p')` line aswell

Comment: yes, the line of code after changing is
p = document.getElementById('chng-txt')

Comment: i have edited, try adding `<script type>`

Comment: tried and nothing happened again...also did <script type="text/javascript"> but no result :(

Comment: check your error console, is it giving any error?? ctr+shift+J. it is working in the fiddle link, right?

Comment: in chrome, I'm getting this -

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: this is BECAUSE the id of the 'P' and the Id inside the document.getElementById('p') is not matching. check again. it is not able to get that ELement.

Comment: i have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3D2r/1/) with your ID

Comment: checked and done exactly in the html doc, the same ID is at both the places...i too changed in fiddle and working fine there...but not in my page..what's wrong there?

even used ur id 'p' in my html, but not worked.

well, I tried invoking alert [alert (p)] just before innerHTML code line...and received following in browser 'null'...does this mean 'p' is not identified?

Comment: remove the `<script>` tag from `<head>` and put it after `<body>`

Comment: hey, its worked...just added before end tag </body>...however, one issue, currently it is counting on number of words, while I need on number of letters including any space.

Comment: so dont split, just do the length, i have edited my solution

Comment: perfectly done :)...though still another point, i've some 8 rows where this type of text is getting displayed...i assumed that keeping same id for all rows, the code will set line-height accordingly of each...however it is working for the first one only and not for remaining 7...using same ID is not the correct approach?

Comment: then instead of ID, add a class. and do `document.getElementsByClassName[]` and do the rest inside a `forloop` for each elements, as `document.getElementsByClassName[]` returns a list of objects

Comment: thanks rhea, i've a class applied with name '.txt-mid'...how to do with loop and in code, can you please provide me that?

Comment: done like a dream, rhea...you're the saviour for me tonight...'thanks a ton' for all your kind support :) ...just wish if i could also have knowledge like you of javascript :P ...but you are a gem of master, thanks again!